# How to trace code path of outgoing ICMP packet in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I want to know after POST_ROUTING point of Linux kernel, what is the code path of outgoing ICMP packet? Which functions are called?
What is the sequence of function calls of outgoing ICMP packet? Can I find this sequence by ftrace?

For example, [how this kernel_flow](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow) is created?

Comment: Google's pretty good at finding information like that.

Comment: @MikeW I want to write a module that do this for me?

Comment: @Khajavi Why? You can send ICMP packets from userspace just fine.

Comment: @MikeW I don't need a fish, I need to now how to fish.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

ICMP packets can originate in two ways:

1. From a userspace socket, e.g. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)`, or a raw socket.
2. From the network stack in the kernel, as a result of some ICMP event, e.g. [ICMP Time Exceeded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded).

Comment: I have created ICMP request packet in linux kernel and inject it in netif_rx(skb), now I want to know which function will be called?

Comment: You're describing an *incoming* packet, but your question asks about *outgoing* packets.

Comment: hmm, yes; it doesn't mind for me, I want know how to find function trace of some event in kernel.

Comment: I can only suggest looking at the [source code](https://www.kernel.org/). Not sure what else you want.

Comment: I want to inject the packet in kernel, and then print the sequence of function calls. reading the source code is tedious. any other way to do this?